# qr code scan result in php

Tags: php, html, qr-code

Is it possible to use html tag in qrcode library?
I tried below code:-

```
header('Content-Type:text/html');
include('../QRcode/qrlib.php');
$html = '<h1><b>BMTF</b></h1>'.PHP_EOL;
$html.= '<h1>Gyldig rapport</h1>'.PHP_EOL;
$html.= '<u></u>'.PHP_EOL;
$tempDir = "QRcodePng/";

//echo QRcode::png($html);
QRcode::png($html, $tempDir.'023.png', QR_ECLEVEL_L, 3); 

echo '<img src="QRcodePng/023.png" />';
```

and I'm getting output like below:-

```
<h1><b>BMTF</b></h1>
<h1>Gyldig rapport</h1>
<u></u>
```

Any suggestion on how to get proper scan output???

Comment: You can put HTML tags in QR code, but it depends if reader supports your HTML. Usually QR code is not intended to be used with HTML

Answer (score 2):

A QR code can only store [some specific data format](http://qrcode.meetheed.com/question13.php) :

- Contact data
- Calendar data
- URL
- Email address
- Phone number
- SMS
- Geolocation
- Plain text

If you store HTML in your QR code, it will be considered as plain text (unless your reader can read HTML). The best way to store HTML in a QR code is to put an URL in the QR Code who redirects to the HTML you want to show.

Comment: how to use that? Are You saying to use like QRcode::png("qrcode.php", $tempDir.$fileName, QR_ECLEVEL_L, 3);

Comment: @ripa No. The only data you put into your QRCode is a link: `http://yourserver.com/yourreport.php` (for example). After that, you create the page `yourreport.php` who generate the HTML you want.

Comment: if I'm putting url like this QRcode::png('http://demo.com/qrcode.php'); then it's giving the url in scan result. Not getting the content of the url. am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @ripa You should write the protocol part: `http://`. http://goqr.me/qr-codes/type-qr-url.html